# Tensor diagrams representing scalars

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

This is probably a silly question. I am reading a paper (arXiv:1910.14662) which employs tensor diagrams, and I have some trouble understanding them. My main issue is the following. When you compute the tensor represented by a diagram, how do you deal with objects such as bilinear forms, which output scalars?

For example, in the paper I am reading, at some point you get a tensor diagram with no inputs and outputs, but multiple bilinear forms involved. I understand that such a diagram represents a scalar, but how do I compute it? Should I multiply all scalars given by the different bilinear forms? And if so, why?